# How to assign the selected value of Drop down to text box

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to assign the selected value in the drop down to text box when ever I hit a button. I'm not able to see the selected value in the `TextBox`. Can someone please let me know what am I missing?

My code is as follows:

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {                       

    }

    protected void Button1_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string strConn = "Initial Catalog=NavigateV6;Data Source=SVUSRYE-SQL3D1;User ID=dopis_user;Password=dopis_password;Persist Security Info=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True";
        SqlConnection mycn = new SqlConnection(strConn);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        SqlDataAdapter myda = new SqlDataAdapter("Select accountid FROM trn_account ", mycn);
        myda.Fill(ds);
        DDL.DataSource = ds;
        DDL.DataTextField = "AccountID";
        DDL.DataValueField = "AccountID";
        DDL.DataBind();

    }



    protected void DDL_SelectedIndexChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var selectedValue = ((DropDownList)sender).SelectedValue;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBox1.Text))
            TextBox1.Text = selectedValue;

    }
}
```

ASPX:

```xml
<asp:DropDownList ID="DDL" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged = " DDL_SelectedIndexChanged" >

    </asp:DropDownList>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click1" 
        Text="sumbit" />
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <br />
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: I tried it but after selecting the drop down value its saying the page cannot be displayed .

Comment: have you considered trying out my suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

jQuery can do that in a snap without a postback:

```
$('#<%= ButtonID.ClientID %>').click(function() {
    $('#<%= TextBoxID.ClientID %>').val($('#<%= DDL_ID.ClientID %>').val());
    return false;
});
```

In fact you don't even need to click a button, it can be done when the user selects a new value in the ddl:

```
$('#<%= DDL_ID.ClientID %>').change(function() {
    $('#<%= TextBoxID.ClientID %>').val($(this).val());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is because when when you check  `(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBox1.Text))`, it always return false because at first stage, value of TextBox is empty and hence never execute inner code of `if condition`.....If you need to go through above condition, you can put some value in `TextBox` at the time of declaration.......

Or,

Simply do like this in `SelectedIndexChanged` of `DropDownList`

```
 var selectedValue = ((DropDownList)sender).SelectedValue;
 TextBox1.Text = selectedValue;
```

Here is working example as like your code:

**ASPX:**

```
<body>
  <form runat="server" id="form1">
        <asp:DropDownList ID="DDL" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
        OnSelectedIndexChanged = "DDL_SelectedIndexChanged" >
      <asp:ListItem Value="One">One</asp:ListItem>
      <asp:ListItem Value="Two">Two</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" 
        Text="sumbit" onclick="Button1_Click" />
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <br />
  </form>
</body>
```

**Code Behind:**

```
 public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void DDL_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var selectedValue = ((DropDownList)sender).SelectedValue;
            TextBox1.Text = selectedValue;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I tried it but after changing the value in the Drop Down its saying that page can not be displayed

Comment: Do you enclosed above html controls inside the form tag with runat= server attribute?

Comment: Yes I did ..Here is the tag  <asp:DropDownList ID="DDL" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged = " DDL_SelectedIndexChanged" >
        
    </asp:DropDownList>

Comment: But still getting kicked off when I am trying to change the value of dropdownlist ..I really dont'understand whats goings on ...

Comment: I posted my aspx code in the top of this page please refer to it